# ThemeData set, but some pages don't follow the ThemData [Flutter] Possible bug?

Tags: flutter, debugging, themes

Has anyone experienced pages not following ThemeData set in material in main.dart?

If anything has gone wrong, I'm cool with it. But some pages follow the theme set, while the others have another theme, I'm not sure why. I haven't written any other code to dictate any new colors or shape for elevated button.

Comment: this will happen if the child widgets does not come under the same tree, where you defined theme. The best way to find out is to open the flutter developer tools and examine the widget state. if that doesn't help, try to come up with a minimal code demonstrating your problem.

Comment: What you have mentioned might be the cause of it, I'll run a check. Thank you MeanMan!

Comment: You're right! Thanks! I've solved it thanks to you